# How to block duplicate orders?

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I am using shopware 6.4.17 and I have a problem with duplicated orders, the order process is a little long so there is a way to send a request once more and put new order from same cart. Is there any way to do not send the same request any more?
Does anyone have the same problem or know the solution?

I am using Varnish so any keys generated in a template are impossible to implement.

Comment: Do you have a MySQL cluster running?

Comment: yes, i have it running

Answer (score 4):

Im assuming you are using multiple app servers. With that in mind, this might be related to missing session locking which allows multiple requests to the same OrderController Endpoint from the user perspective. With session locking, only the first request is allowed to proceed to the controller. Any other request waits for the first request to finish, therefore preventing duplicate orders.

PHP is using session locking by default when you use the default session handlers. Internally its just a `flock` thats used for file based sessions.

Also see https://symfony.com/doc/current/session.html for more informations.

For Redis this php.ini config should work:

```
session.save_handler = redis
session.save_path = "tcp://redis:6379"
redis.session.locking_enabled = 1
```